# Access DlookUp not working with multiple Criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access

The Dlookup Function is Giving me a syntax error I have tried multiple ways but none worked

```
x = DLookup("Clock_ID", "User_access", "Clock = " '" & Me.Clock_ID & _
         & " AND Module = '" & Me.m_1 & "'")
```

I basically Need it to check 2 fields in the same table at the same time so the ID can be duplicated But the Module cant be duplicated.

Comment: Too many `"` marks. Remove the one after `Clock = `. Why would Clock and Module have same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess ID is numeric, so try:

```
x = DLookup("Clock_ID", "User_access", "Clock = " & Me.Clock_ID & " AND Module = '" & Me.m_1 & "'")
```

Comment: It shows me Run time Error "2471" The Expression you entered as a query Parameter Produced this error "Clock"

Comment: Then you either need the quotes, or you don't have a field named Clock.